# python pygame - how to create a drag and drop with multiple images?

Tags: python, image, drag-and-drop, pygame

So I've been trying to create a jigsaw puzzle using pygame in python.The only problem is that I'm having trouble creating the board with multiple images that i can drag along the screen (no need to connect the images like a puzzle what so ever just a simple drag and drop). I'm loading my images from a local folder on my computer. 
Can someone please help me?

This is what i have tried so far but the images start at the same postion and pygame recognize them all as one image

```
import socket
import os
import shutil
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*



def dragdrop(path):
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
        fullname=os.path.join("data", name)
        try:
            image=pygame.image.load(fullname)
        except pygame.error, message:
            print "Impossible de charger l'image:",name
            raise SystemExit, message
        image = image.convert()
        if colorkey is not None:
            if colorkey is -1:
                colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
            image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
        return image, image.get_rect()

    class Ichrom(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self,image,initpos):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.pos = initpos
            self.image, self.rect=image
            self.button=(0,0,0)#mouse buttons not pressed
            self.selected = 0
            self.mouseover=False
            self.focused=False
            print "init chrom at ",self.pos

        def rollover(self):
            """Test if the mouse fly over the chromosome 
            self.mouseover==True if mouse flying over the chrom,
            False if not"""
            mpos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()#mouseposition
            #test if mouse roll over the sprite
            if self.rect.collidepoint(mpos):
                self.mouseover=True
            else:
                self.mouseover=False
        def update(self):
            self.button=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self.selected=self.rect.collidepoint(mpos)
            #the mouse flies over a chromosome
            if (self.mouseover):
                #print "mouse pos:",mpos
                if self.button==(1,0,0):     # )  
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    self.rect.midtop = pos

    def main():
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Karyotyper")
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

        background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
        background = background.convert()
        background.fill((0, 0, 0))

        screen.blit(background,(0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()


        """i1=load_image('C:/Users/Yonatan/Desktop/House.png', -1)
        i2=load_image('C:/Users/Yonatan/Desktop/US.jpeg', -1)
        i3=load_image('C:\Users\Yonatan\Desktop\imgres.jpg', -1)
        fuck= [i1, i2, i3]"""

        img=[]
        count=0
        for i in dirs:

            spr = Ichrom(load_image(path + "/" +i,-1),(count,count))
            count = count+30
            img.append(spr)

        allsprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((fck))
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        while 1:
            clock.tick(60)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    return
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    return
                if event.type ==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    #need to be modified to handle a list of chromosomes
                    for i in fck:
                        i.rollover()
            allsprites.update()
            screen.blit(background,(0,0))
            allsprites.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()

    main()
```

Comment: im having trouble with moving the images. i load them all to the board but i load them at the same rect and im having trouble loading them at different postion. then the pygame recognize them all as one picture

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far?

Comment: i edited the question just now

Comment: See also [Drag multiple sprites with different “update ()” methods from the same Sprite class in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419223/drag-multiple-sprites-with-different-update-methods-from-the-same-sprite-cl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a position to your sprites and store it in `self.pos`, but to draw a `Sprite` a sprite group uses the `rect` attribute:

From [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the Sprite.image attribute for the source surface, and Sprite.rect for the position.

Comment: Thank you so much sloth i finally figured it out!