# How to draw a chessboard with Pygame and move the pieces on the board?

Tags: python, pygame, chess, pygame-surface

I've been trying different ways how to get my chess pieces to drag and drop I've found ways, but the problem is that I'm using a dictionary to load my images via `pygame.image.load`. I've created a dictionary for my images like this:

```
IMAGES = {}

def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = pygame.transform.scale(
                            pygame.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), 
                                              (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
    # Note we can access an image by saying "IMAGES['wp']'
```

I've been through these questions for sprite drop and drag:
[How to move Sprite in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183265/how-to-move-sprite-in-pygame)

[Drag multiple sprites with different "update ()" methods from the same Sprite class in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419223/drag-multiple-sprites-with-different-update-methods-from-the-same-sprite-cl)

[python pygame - how to create a drag and drop with multiple images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751547/python-pygame-how-to-create-a-drag-and-drop-with-multiple-images)

I've attempted many of these, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement any of them in my code for image dictionaries. I'm just lost. I need help. If you need anymore information or code let me know.

Comment: What part of the dragging and dropping, but using a directory of images, is giving you problems — you need to be more specific. That's a big part of the reason folks are encouraged to always include code with their own attempt in their questions here. Referencing several other questions is no substitute.

Comment: Hi~ It is a little hard to reproduce the code according to the current statement. If it is possible to give more coding information?

Comment: Do not create a dictionary of images, but a dictionary of `Sprite` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create[`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects with the images.
Create a dictionary with the sprites from the dictionary with the images.
You have to create a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object for each piece.
Hence you have to create 8 *Sprites* with the image of the white pawn.
Create 1 dictionary for the white pieces and one for the black pieces.
Add all the pices to one [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
class ChessSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, i, j, image):
        super().__init__() 
        # [...]
```

```py
white = {}
for i, f in enumerate(['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']):
    white[f] = ChessSprite(i, 0, IMAGES[f])
for i in range(8):
    pawn_name = 'wp' + str(i+1)
    white[pawn_name] = ChessSprite(i, 1, IMAGES['wp'])

black = {}
for i, f in enumerate(['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR']):
    black[f] = ChessSprite(i, 7, IMAGES[f])
for i in range(8):
    pawn_name = 'bp' + str(i+1)
    black[pawn_name] = ChessSprite(i, 6, IMAGES['bp'])

group = pygame.sprite.Group()
group.add(white.values())
group.add(black.values())
```

With this setup you can drag each piece individually. See [Draw Sprite](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md#drag-sprite) and [Drag multiple sprites with different “update ()” methods from the same Sprite class in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419223/drag-multiple-sprites-with-different-update-methods-from-the-same-sprite-cl/64456959#64456959).

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

class DragOperator:
    def __init__(self, sprite):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.dragging = False
        self.rel_pos = (0, 0)
    def update(self, event_list):
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                self.dragging = self.sprite.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
                self.rel_pos = event.pos[0] - self.sprite.rect.x, event.pos[1] - self.sprite.rect.y
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                self.dragging = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and self.dragging:
                self.sprite.rect.topleft = event.pos[0] - self.rel_pos[0], event.pos[1] - self.rel_pos[1]

class ChessSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, board_rect, i, j, image):
        super().__init__() 
        self.board = board_rect
        self.image = image 
        self.set_pos(i, j)
        self.drag = DragOperator(self)
    def set_pos(self, i, j):
        x = self.board.left + self.board.width // 8 * i + self.board.width // 16
        y = self.board.left + self.board.height // 8 * (7 - j) + self.board.height // 16
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
    def update(self, event_list):
        self.drag.update(event_list)
        if not self.drag.dragging:
            i = max(0, min(7, (self.rect.centerx - self.board.left) // (self.board.width // 8)))
            j = 7 - max(0, min(7, (self.rect.centery - self.board.top) // (self.board.height // 8)))
            self.set_pos(i, j)
        
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

board = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
board.fill((255, 255, 255))
size = (min(window.get_size()) - 20) // 8
start = (window.get_width() - size * 8) // 2, (window.get_height() - size * 8) // 2
board_rect = pygame.Rect(*start, size*8, size*8)
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
for y in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        color = (192, 192, 164) if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else (96, 64, 32)
        pygame.draw.rect(board, color, (start[0]+ x*size, start[1] + y*size, size, size))

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode
white_figures = { 'king': '♔', 'queen': '♕', 'rook': '♖', 'bishop': '♗', 'knight': '♘', 'pawn': '♙'}
black_figures = { 'king': '♚', 'queen': '♛', 'rook': '♜', 'bishop': '♝', 'knight': '♞', 'pawn': '♟'}

seguisy = pygame.font.SysFont("segoeuisymbol", size-4)
white_images = { k : seguisy.render(c, True, (255, 255, 255)) for k, c in white_figures.items() }
black_images = { k : seguisy.render(c, True, (0, 0, 0)) for k, c in black_figures.items() } 

group = pygame.sprite.Group()
figures = ['rook', 'knight', 'bishop', 'queen', 'king', 'bishop', 'knight', 'rook']
for i, figure in enumerate(figures):
    group.add(ChessSprite(board_rect, i, 0, white_images[figure]))
    group.add(ChessSprite(board_rect, i, 1, white_images['pawn']))
    group.add(ChessSprite(board_rect, i, 7, black_images[figure]))
    group.add(ChessSprite(board_rect, i, 6, black_images['pawn']))
   
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    group.update(event_list)

    window.blit(board, (0, 0))
    group.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```